# How/Where to store temporary data without using claim check pattern?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a usecase that requires our application to send a notification to an external system in case when a particular event occurs. The notification to external system happens by putting a message into a JMS queue.

The transactional requirements are not that strict. Hence, instead of using JTA for such a trivial usecase I decided to use JMS local transaction, as spring understands how to synchronize JMS local transaction with any managed transaction(e.g. database transaction) to elevate 1PC.

The problem I am facing is that the notification has to be enriched with some data before sending the notification. This extra information has no relevance to my business domain which is responsible for generating the event. So, I am not sure where to temporary store that extra data to reclaim it before sending the notification. Probably, below illustration may help in understanding the problem.

HTTP Request ---> Rest API ---> Application Domain ---> Event Generation ---> Notification

As per the above illustration I do not want to pass that extra data and pollute my domain layer, which is part of Rest API request payload, to send the notification.

One solution I thought of is to use thread scoped queue channel to reclaim it before sending the notification. This way Rest API will initiate the process by putting the extra data into the queue and before sending the notification I will pull it from the queue to enrich the message for notification.

The part which I am unable to achieve in this solution is that how to pull the message from queue when I receive the event somewhere in the application (between event generation and notification phase).

If my approach does not make any sense than please suggest any solution without using claim/check pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply store the information in a header (or headers)? The domain layer doesn't need to know it's there.

Or, for your solution, create a new `QueueChannel` for each request, and store a reference to it in a header and `receive()` from it on the back end, but it's easier to just use a header directly.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention in the question is that the call to domain layer is not happening as part of spring integration flow. If we want to store the information in the header do we have to make the call to service as part of flow?

Comment: It depends on how your domain layer is architected. If your domain service is a POJO, invoke it from a `<service-activator/>` and the framework will take care of unwrapping the message payload for the service, and maintaining the headers for downstream use.

Comment: As you said that you forgot something to mention, we really can't help you without more info on the matter. From other side you always can store that info somewhere in the external store or just in the `RequestAttributes` and use `RequestContextHolder` for the `ThreadLocal` logic.